# Let $f(a) = \int^a_0 \ln (1+\tan a \tan x)\,dx $ then find $f'(\frac{\pi}{4})$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Problem:
>   If $\displaystyle f(a) = \int^a_0 \ln (1+\tan a \tan x)\,dx $ then find $f'(\frac{\pi}{4})$

My approach:

\begin{align}
f(a) &= \int^a_0 \ln (1+\tan a \tan x)\,dx \\[6px]
&=\int^a_0 \ln (1+\tan a \tan(a-x))\,dx \\[6px]
&= \int^a_0 \ln \left(1+\tan a \frac{\tan a -\tan x}{1+\tan a \tan x}\right)\,dx\\[6px]
&= \int^a_0 \ln (1+\tan^2a)\,dx
\end{align}

Is it the right approach? Please further suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: What is tanatan?

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=\int_0^{x}\ln\left(1+\tan(x)\tan(t)\right)dt$ and use this fact that $$f'(x)=\int_0^{x}[\ln\left(1+\tan(x)\tan(t)\right)]_xdt+\ln(1+\tan^2(x))$$ However, this may make it difficult to find.

Comment: You're missing the denominator.

Comment: i have got $$1/2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +\pi /4$$

Answer (score 5):

From the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$f'(a)=\log(1+\tan^2(a))+\int_0^a \frac{\sec^2(a)\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(a)}\,dx$$

Therefore,

$$f'(\pi/4)=\log(2)+\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{2\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)}\,dx=\frac12\log(2)+\pi/4$$

Comment: can u elaborate a little bit on this, will be of great help. thanks

Comment: no that is not case

Answer (score 3):

It's good until
$$
\int^a_0 \ln \left(1+\tan a \frac{\tan a -\tan x}{1+\tan a \tan x}\right)\,dx
$$
but then you forget the denominator; instead you get
$$
\int_0^a\ln\frac{1+\tan^2a}{1+\tan a\tan x}\,dx=
\int_0^a\ln(1+\tan^2a)\,dx-\int_0^a\ln(1+\tan a\tan x)\,dx
$$
So, in the end,
$$
f(a)=\int_0^a\ln(1+\tan^2a)\,dx-f(a)
$$
I'm sure you can finish, now, because the integral is elementary.

Comment: Simplest answer without the need to differentiate the integral with respect to parameter $a$. +1 and happy new year.